# horizontal bars icon like twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create the options icon like the twitter bootstrap icon on top right when screen is reduced to @media(mobile~) width. I did a bit of reverse engineering and was able to recreate the icon on Chrome and Safari. However it looks a little different in Firefox and drastically different in IE8.

[image: Image in Various browsers]

Looking for help to fix this.

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="optionspanel.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>
      <button type="button" class="fw-opt-panel">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a id="optionsicon" href="#" class="selected"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="selected">Item 02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 03</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.fw-opt-panel {
  background-color: rgb(14, 14, 14);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(21, 21, 21), rgb(4, 4, 4));
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.247059);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0980392) 0px 1px 0px 0px inset, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0745098) 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 7px;
}

.icon-bar {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 18px;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use the [triple bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_bar) Unicode character - ☰ (U+2630). It's also available in lots of different icon fonts which fix cross-browser differences, like Font Awesome or [Entypo](http://entypo.com).

Answer (score 0):

IE 6-9 doesn't render radius, gradients, or text-shadow the way you'd expect it to (or at all).

Try using PIE (see [PIE example here](http://css3pie.com/)).

As for Firefox, it, too, likes to be pointed at when you generate a gradient or a radius. Use -moz-linear-gradient in addition to webkit.